# Insert Jquery AJAX result into TBODY on IE doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I've been using this jquery function :

```
<script>
function insertData(value1){
    $.get( "thisfile.php", { row1: value1} )
    .done(function( data ) {
    $("#tbody1").html( data );
    });
};
</script>
```

with this link as trigger :

```
<a href='#' onClick='insertData("test")'>Click Me</a>
```

to show the value on this php :

```
if($_GET['row1'] == 'test'){
echo "<tr><td>Peter Parker</td></tr><tr><td>Marry Jane</td></tr><tr><td>Aunt May</td></tr>";
}
```

to show the value on this html :

```
<table>
<tbody><tr><th>Name</th></tr></tbody>
<tbody id='tbody1'></tbody>
</table>
```

On other browser like chrome and firefox, it works just fine, even in IE 10. But when i used below IE 9, the value doesn't show. Can anyone help me to show the value on IE 9 below? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Is the AJAX call returning successfully?  Try `console.log`ing `data`.

Comment: the AJAX call returning successfully. It showed up on Chrome and Firefox, but it won't show up on IE 6 to 9. I think it's because the tbody, but i can't figure out how to fix it. Because when i use div, instead of tbody, it showed up perfectly on IE 6-9.

Answer (score 1):

You **HTML** is wrong, use `tbody` only once(it may create problems in **IE**) like,

```
<table>
   <thead><tr><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
   <tbody id='tbody1'></tbody>
</table>
```